# iOS 11 Cookie Changes - Seeking technical explanation

Tags: cookies, ios11

iOS 11 apparently brings significant changes to the way cookies work.

Can someone provide me with a comprehensive, technically detailed description of the exact behaviour changes?

If we're all going to need to make modifications to the way our site's work to support this, this feels like an important question/thread to populate with concise details as a reference for everyone.

The best I can find are articles like this:

https://adexchanger.com/data-driven-thinking/apples-upcoming-safari-changes-will-shake-ad-tech/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual feature of concern is Webkit's Intelligent Tracking Prevention.

This is covered in a post on the Webkit blog: https://webkit.org/blog/7675/intelligent-tracking-prevention

I'll attempt to summarise for the benefit of SO:

The intention is that third-party cookies from sites that are determined to perform *Cross-site tracking* can only be available on your site if the user is an **active user** of the third party site.

A machine learning algorithm, on device, makes the determination that a site is doing cross-site tracking. The exact conditions that would trigger this determination are not made clear in the blog post.

Example:

Using AdTech Co as an example, and Foo.com as your site.

- you have AdTech Co tracking code on your site, `foo.com` which relies on a `adtech.com` cookie to identify the user.
- `adtech.com` is a third-party cookie, it isn't a subdomain of `foo.com`, it has already been determined to be a *Cross site tracker*
- Whether the user is an active user of AdTech Co is tracked by the browser - have they actually browsed adtech.com as a user?

If the user has actually browsed `adtech.com` in the past day:

- Cookies work as normal

If the user has browsed `adtech.com` between 1-30 days ago:

- Cookies are *partitioned*, meaning that `adtech.com` cookies can be stored and retrieved, but are scoped to `foo.com`. AdTech Co code running on `bar.com` would not be able to read these cookies, even though they are owned by `adtech.com`

If the user hasn't browsed `adtech.com` in 30 days:

- The cookies are purged entirely

Here's the image from the blog post showing these rules:

[image: Third party cookie rules]

Comment: What constitutes "actually browsed"? Thanks.

Comment: @StevenFrancolla Physically visited the domain in question. So if your browser doesn't browse to adtech.com, and only pulls in content via other domains (i.e. an advert on the foo.com website), but you never actually visit the adtech.com domain, or, I believe a subdomain of that website, then the cookie issues from that domain will be partitioned / purged, depending on timescales.

Comment: Has anyone else seen where first party cookies are not being stored/purged correctly as well? We are experiencing issues with our app where even the first party cookies we are using for authentication in our home screen web app are being persisted after logging out and expiring the cookie. Thread posted here shows a really simplified version of what we are experiencing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551996/ios-11-cookie-expiration-in-home-screen-web-apps